# How to automatically apply modifications to all/some fields of a case class in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, newtype, opaque-types

I'm currently challenging myself to skill up in Scala and FP. And today:

- I came up with an issue that might interest you, devil prog masters ;)

---

Let's say I have the following case class in scala 3:

```
type EmailAddress = String // I defined them like that to show I'm interested in
type PhoneNumber = String // ... attributes via their names, not via their types.
case class Person(name: String, emails: List[EmailAddress], phones: List[PhoneNumber])
```

I would like to have a method that **automatically transform** (almost) all **fields**.
For example, I would like to order `emails` with the **default given instance** of Ordering[String] and  `phones` with a **specified one**.
Ideally I should be **able to exclude** `name` **field**.

So I would get something like:

```
/* Below, I represented the kind of parametrization I would like to be able to do 
 * as parameters of the method orderValues,
 * but it could be annotations or meta-programming instead.
 * 
 * An `orderedPerson` can be directly an instance of Person
 * or something else like an OderedEntity[Person], I don't care so far.
 */
val orderedPerson =
  person.orderValues(
    excluded = Set("name"),
    explicitRules = Map(
      // Phones would have a special ordering (reverse is just a dummy value)
      "phones" -> Ordering.String.reverse
    )
  )

// -----

// So we would get:
Person(
  name = "Xiao",
  emails = List("a@a.a", "a@a.b", "a@b.a"),
  phones = List("+86 100 9000 1000", "+86 100 2000 1000")
)
```

I haven't used Reflection for a long time and I'm not yet familiar with Meta-Programming, but I'm open to any solution that can help me to achieve that.
It's a good opportunity for learning !

---

[Edit]

My intentional intent was to have a library that can be use to easily anonymize any data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` keyword in Scala is just a type alias. You should use a `newtype` library like https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype (or `opaque type` in Scala 3) and derive implicit instances of Ordering from String

Example with `estatico/scala-newtype`:

```scala
import io.estatico.newtype.macros.newtype
import io.estatico.newtype.ops._

@newtype case class Email(string: String)
object Email {
  implicit val ordering: Ordering[Email] = deriving
}
@newtype case class PhoneNumber(string: String)
object PhoneNumber {
  implicit val ordering: Ordering[PhoneNumber] = deriving[Ordering].reverse
}
case class Person(name: String, emails: List[Email], phones: List[PhoneNumber]) {
  lazy val orderValues: Person = this.copy(emails = emails.sorted, phones = phones.sorted)
}

Person(
  "Xiao",
  List(Email("a@a.a"), Email("a@a.b"), Email("a@b.a")),
  List(PhoneNumber("+86 100 9000 1000"), PhoneNumber("+86 100 2000 1000"))
).orderValues
```

Comment: This is a a really interesting answer, that reply very well to the concrete question I asked, thanks!

However, assuming I want to publish a library of preset orderings, how would a dev be able to use this lib ?
I can imagine suggesting devs to:
-＞ extends types with new methods ;
-＞ defining givens instances based on imported lib's givens within their own opaque types.
But would it be user-friendly enough?

Actually Ordering is an example, so my question is ,ore generic to any class that would be used like Ordering is (implicit / given).

Comment: @BRUNIERTerry You can't extend a case class. You can use @newsubtype for a subtype relationship but subtyping is irrelevant here. There's is also no need for subtyping to write new methods for a type. Method extensions can be implemented with implicits. Besides, you can always write an infix method `a.method(b)` as a prefix function `function(a, b)`.

Comment: You don't always need to define `Ordering` from scratch for a new type, you can always transform from the `Ordering` of an existing type. In fact, if you model your types as Algebraic Data Types of existing types then the can get default instances of  `Ordering` for ally your types for free with automatic derivation.

Comment: `Ordering` is a typeclass and typeclasses supports ad-hoc polymorphism as oppose to subtype polymorphism that OOP advocates. Imagine having another `Order` trait functionally equivalent `Ordering` but allows you to `extends` as a subtype, and imagine `Person` is an imported 3rd party type that neither extends `Order` nor comes with an `Ordering` instance.

Comment: As a 3rd party lib user, you won't be able to extend `Person` with `Order` but can still instantiate an `Ordering` instance for `Person` for a generic sorting function to work. With OOP you might be able to resort to some GoF patterns... but how is that user-friendly?

Comment: Like for the case of `Person`, because it is a product type, and because we already know the `Ordering` of `String`, `Email`, `PhoneNumber` and `List[A]` (for any `A` given `Ordering[A]`), we can get `Ordering[Person]` for free.

Comment: If you `import Ordering.Implicits._` you will see that `Ordering[(String, Email, PhoneNumber)]` and subsequently `Ordering[Option[(String, List[Email], List[PhoneNumber])]]` already compiles in vanilla Scala, and `Ordering[Person]` is just `Ordering[Option[(String, List[Email], List[PhoneNumber])]].on(Person.unapply)`. You can see how this is just a few steps away for automatically deriving `Ordering` for `Person` or any other case classes.