# How to return values with nested Reader monads with cats?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, functional-programming, scala-cats

Is there a way to avoid calling the "run" method twice and doing it just once from the main method or this is the right way to do it in nested Readers?

```
  case class Dependencies(showService: ShowService, sumService: SumService)

  class ShowService {
    def show(s: String): IO[Unit] = IO {println(s)}
  }

  class SumService() {
    def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Reader[Dependencies, IO[Int]] = Reader {_ => IO {a + b} }
  }

  object ModuleA {
    def sumAndShow: ReaderT[IO, Dependencies, Unit] = for {
      x <- ReaderT[IO, Dependencies, Int] (deps => deps.sumService.sum(10, 10).run(deps))
      r <- ReaderT[IO, Dependencies, Unit] (deps => deps.showService.show(x.toString))
    } yield r
  }
  
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val dependencies = Dependencies(new ShowService, new SumService)
    ModuleA.sumAndShow.run(dependencies) *> IO(ExitCode.Success)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you choose to define your services this way but if your question is to avoid calling `run` in `sumAndShow` you could lift your `Reader`/`IO` into `ReaderT`s with `lift`/`liftF` and compose them with a `ReaderT.ask`:

```scala
def sumAndShow: ReaderT[IO, Dependencies, Unit] =
  for {
    deps <- ReaderT.ask[IO, Dependencies]
    x <- deps.sumService.sum(10, 10).lift[IO].flatMap(ReaderT.liftF)
    r <- ReaderT.liftF(deps.showService.show(x.toString))
  } yield r
```

Alternative generic implementation with existing typeclass constraints with Cats/Cats Effect, and also how `newtype` could be used for alternative typeclass instances:

```scala
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect._
import cats.effect.std.Console
import cats.{Semigroup, Show}
import io.estatico.newtype.macros.newtype


object Main extends IOApp {
  @newtype case class MInt(value: Int)
  object MInt {
    implicit val multiplicativeSemigroup: Semigroup[MInt] =
      deriving(Semigroup.instance(_ * _))
    implicit val show: Show[MInt] = deriving
  }

  def sumAndShow[F[_]: Console, A: Show: Semigroup](a: A, b: A): F[Unit] =
    Console[F].println(a |+| b)

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    for {
      _ <- sumAndShow[IO, Int](10, 10) //20

      //you can also "inject" default/custom typeclass "dependencies" explicitly
      _ <- sumAndShow[IO, Int](10, 10)(Console[IO], Show[Int], Semigroup.instance(_ * _)) //100

      //custom typeclass instance with newtype
      _ <- sumAndShow[IO, MInt](MInt(10), MInt(10)) //100

      _ <- sumAndShow[IO, String]("Hello", "World") //HelloWorld
    } yield ExitCode.Success
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. I didn't define the services that way for no special reason but since you mentioned that, what's the best way specify several dependencies including dependencies that are shared by several components?

Comment: Firstly, `Reader[Dependencies, IO[Int]]` is really awkward type which could have been easily refactored to `ReaderT[IO, Dependencies, Int]` or `Reader[Dependencies, Int]`.
I understand that you want generic implementation for your services but it kind of forces your `sum` to be unnecessarily wrapped in an `IO` and depend on `Dependencies` where it could have just return an `Int` and get lifted into a `ReaderT` when needed.

Comment: You should look into `Show` and `Console` typeclasses in Cats/Cats Effect. Wrapping services in case classes is fine but you don't need to view everything as a service if all you need is to do things generically.

To have multiple typeclasses instances for the same types you can encode them as new types. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569306/how-to-automatically-apply-modifications-to-all-some-fields-of-a-case-class-in-s/68570792#68570792

Comment: Then when you comfortable with typeclass constraints you can read up on "tagless final" and MTL.

Comment: I've added an example where `ShowService` is replaced by `Console` and `Show`, and `SumService` is replaced by `Semigroup`.

Comment: Updated with an example on how `newtype` can be used.